AdMob Banner Ad in Jetpack Compose Not Adjusting to Screen Width Properly in Landscape Mode
I am trying to integrate AdMob banners in my Jetpack Compose application. However, I am facing an issue where the banner ads do not adjust correctly to the screen width in landscape mode. The container adjusts correctly, but the ad content does not scale properly.
Here is my Compose code:
private const val BANNER_AD_TEST_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var adView: AdView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        MobileAds.initialize(this)

        loadBannerAd()

        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Banner()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Banner() {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            adView?.let { adView ->
                AndroidView(
                    factory = { adView },
                    update = { loadBannerAd() },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadBannerAd() {
        // Destroy the old adView
        this.adView?.destroy()

        // Determine adSize
        val displayMetrics = this.resources.displayMetrics
        val screenWidth = (displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density).toInt()
        val adSize = AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, screenWidth)

        // Create new adView
        val adView = AdView(this)
        adView.adUnitId = BANNER_AD_TEST_ID
        adView.setAdSize(adSize)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        adView.loadAd(adRequest)

        // Update adView
        this.adView = adView
    }
}

I have also referred to this Google AdMob Banner Example using Views, which adjusts perfectly (or at least much better) to the screen width.
Screenshots:
Here is a link to screenshots of both versions.
What I Need to Know:

Why is my Compose implementation behaving differently from the Views example?
How can I get the actual content of the ad container to adjust to the full width of the screen, similar to the Views example?

Additional Context:

The banner ad is loaded, but it doesn't resize properly when the orientation changes.
I have verified that the adSize is calculated correctly.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
